# Приложение нельзя открыть

Tags: android, android-studio

После очередного adb debug-a в Android Studio, debug сборки приложения пропали из меню, а при установке кнопка "открыть" неактивна.
В чем причина такого поведения?

Comment: Не хватает информации. Поясните что значит `debug сборки приложения пропали из меню` и что за кнопка `открыть`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в результате Ваших изменений в манифесте не осталось активити с интент-фильтром `MAIN` `LAUNCHER`, который является обозначением точки входа в приложение

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

На самом деле в лаунчере отображаются не приложения, а активности с таким фильтром, если в приложении таких нет, то увидеть его можно только в меню приложений в настройках и запустить напрямую не получится, так как нет точки входа.

Comment: Да нет, action.MAIN я полез проверять в первую очередь. В итоге, скопировал исходники, и воспользовался бэкапом. Не смотря на то, что код один и тот-же, теперь всё работает. А за полезную информацию насчет активностей в лаунчере - спасибо! Я раньше не сильно заморачивался насчет манифеста)

Comment: Должен быть и экшен и категория. А сама активити на месте? - если Вы в студии, то зажмите `ctrl` и кликните по имени в манифесте - должен открыться её класс. Ну и попробуйте стандартный набор фиксов - `Rebuild Project`, `Invalidate Catches`, удаление приложения с девайса и установка "на чистую".

Comment: Может, надо было до восстановления бэкапа всё протыкать.

Comment: Ну да, зачем ковырять то что уже работает)